# Получение значение переменной из цикла while в другом месте в коде

Tags: java

Может я чего-то не до конца понимаю, но как можно получить значение переменной id где-нибудь в коде, помимо это метода.

```
 public static int Mehotd A(int b){

     .....

    try {

     ........

        while (resultSet.next()) {
          String id = resultSet.getString(1);



        }

    } catch (Exception e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    return b;

}
```

Comment: .........зачем?

Comment: Можете в нужном месте получать resultSet, можете переделать этот метод, чтобы он возвращал объект, включающий этот id, и вызывать передалнный метод где нужно... Много чего можно придумать, все зависит от вашей задачи.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Переменные, которые заданные в блоках кода между скобками «{» и «}», в методе, существуют только в этом блоке. То есть в данном случае переменная видна только в в блоке while (...). Если вы хотите, чтобы переменная была видна во всём методе, то объявите её раньше, вот так:

```
public static int Mehotd A(int b){
String id;
.....
try {
 ........
    while (resultSet.next()) {
      id = resultSet.getString(1);)
...
```

А если хотите, чтобы переменная id была видна за пределами метода, то объявите ещё раньше, перемененной класса, а потом или передаривайте её  в метод, как указано выше, или делайте статичной.

Answer (score 3):

Есть несколько вариантов. Во-первых, можно создать поле класса, в которое записывать значение переменной id. Второй - написать метод, наподобие:  
`private String getId(String id) { 
     return id; 
}`.  
С моей точки зрения, это логичнее. Но если у Вас возникают такие вопросы, то значит Вы не до конца поняли идеи областей видимости, а, значит, и ООП. Советую почитать что-нибудь на эту тему